# I'm attempting to copy a range with variable arguments

Tags: excel

I've tried the following unsuccessfully.

```
Sub TestRange()

    Dim example As Range

    Dim RangeStart As Long

    Dim RangeEnd As Long

    RangeStart = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)

    RangeEnd = ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 4)


    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet5")

    With ws

        example = ws.Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        Set example = Range(.Cells(RangeStart, 1), .Cells(RangeEnd, 8))

    End With

    example.Select

    Selection.Copy

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow.  What problem are you having? are you receiving na error of some kind? Could you add some additional details possibly? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You're missing the `.` in `.Range` that defines the copy area within the With/End With block.

```
Dim example As Range
Dim RangeStart As Long, RangeEnd As Long

RangeStart = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)
RangeEnd = ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 4)

With Worksheets("Sheet5")

    'I don't know what the following is intended to do - it has no purpose
    'example = ws.Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set example = .Range(.Cells(RangeStart, 1), .Cells(RangeEnd, 8))

End With

example.copy
```